# Possible to prevent init from being called?

Tags: python, initialization

I'm editing the original question because we're all focusing on SHOULD you ever want to do this.  My question is simply CAN I do this and HOW (understanding that there may be several solutions).  So I'm just going to leave the actual question and cut out the background.

Suppose I have a base class and a child class.  Is there anything I can do in the base class to prevent __init__ from being called on the child class - or at least throw an exception or even log if __init__ exists or is called on the child class?  I do want the __init__ method to be called on the parent class.

**Edit/Conclusion** - After exploring the options presented in the answers, I decided that doing this would be bad style.  I will solve my problem a different way.  Nonetheless, hopefully the answers below are helpful in case someone else wants to do this.

Comment: Add a comment: "Do not override the `__init__` method". Trust your users. Also, smart users would know how to use `super`

Comment: I don't see the need to f*** with `__init__`, the class can simply keep track of whether `state_entry()` has been invoked and refuse to do anything until then.

Comment: These are helpful suggestions but I'm curious if this can be technically done.  Whether or not I should or need to do it is a separate discussion :)

Comment: @MatthewLund Since Python is very open with its internals anything could potentially be done. So the answer is yes it can be done. Answering HOW to do that would be a waste of time for most of us. But feel free to open that separate discussion.

Comment: I think I made it pretty clear in the post that the HOW is what I'm asking.  I often feel damned-if-I-do and damned-if-I-don't in terms of providing background...  If I simply post the actual question everyone says "give us background, we need to know why you want to do this".  If I do give background everyone just acknowledges it can be done (without mentioning the HOW) and debates whether it should be done.  I'm all for debating the should be sometimes I just what to know CAN it be done and HOW.  Once I have that information I'm in a better position to answer SHOULD for myself :)

Comment: @MatthewLund I think the comments area is for this of information trade. The pattern you propose is somewhat crazy for many eyes and some people may show you better approaches without directly answering your question. On my answer I showed "HOW" but I strong discourage you from using such code and I couldn't have written it without the warning on the top. That would be like: "Yes, you can kill a person with the XYZ poison" and not telling you not to do so.

Comment: I appreciate everything you've posted.  Understanding the how may very well help me understand why I shouldn't do it.  In this case it's also a specific "itch" that even if I later abandon (with good reason perhaps), it'll have been a good exercise to learn more about metaclasses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's quite doable, but I don't think you should.
Tell the users how to use your class and they should obey. Also, if someone is subclassing he should know how to call the parent's initialization method.

As a proof of concept, here's how it can be done with metaclasses (Python 2.x syntax):

```
>>> class WhoMovedMyInit(object):
        class __metaclass__(type):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
                super(type,self).__init__(*args, **kw)
                if self.__init__ is not WhoMovedMyInit.__init__:
                    raise Exception('Dude, I told not to override my __init__')


>>> class IAmOk(WhoMovedMyInit):
        pass

>>> class Lol(WhoMovedMyInit):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    class Lol(WhoMovedMyInit):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 6, in __init__
    raise Exception('Dude, I told not to override my __init__')
Exception: Dude, I told not to override my __init__
```

You can also replace the subclass `__init__` method to one which warns the user or raises an error on "runtime".

Answer (score 18):

" Whether or not I should or need to do it is a separate discussion :)"

Please, keep that in mind.

But it can be done - when a class is instantiated, not only the syntax is just like
a method call - with the class object name followed y a parenthesis - the class itself (which is a Python object), is called - as a callable object.

Calling an object in Python invokes the  `__call__` magic method in its class. Therefore, instantiating a class, invokes the `__call__` method on its metaclass.

What is inside this `__call__` method in the standard metaclass (which is "type") is roughly equivalent to:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
    self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    cls.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
    return self
```

So, if you write a metaclass, overriding `__call__` and suppress the call to `__init__` in these, it won't be called at all:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)

class NoInit(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hello!"

NoInit()
```

If you want just to avoid that sublcasses have `__init__` instead of not calling it, you can do a much simpler metaclass that would just raise an exception at class instantiation time:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
         if "__init__" in dct:
              raise NameError("Classes in this hierarchy should not have an __init__ method")
         return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers are outdated.

This can be easily done since python 3.6. It was defined in [PEP487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/).

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if Base.__init__ is not cls.__init__:
            raise Exception(f'Do not override {cls}.__init__')

class Good(Base):
    pass

class Bad(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

Good() # No problem
Bad()  # Raises Exception
```

Comment: Be aware that `assert` statements are disabled when running `python` with the `-O` flag.

Comment: This will fail if run with `-O`.  Please fix the check so it will not fail in that case.

Comment: Fixed. See above.