# Import Python class that only has `__new__` into Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Have a python class that is imported in Robot Framework as follows:

**Python:** `MyClass.py`

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        # implementation here
```

**Robot Framework:** `MyTest.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Library    MyClass.py    a=1    b=2
```

Getting the error `Error in file 'MyTest.robot': Test Library 'MyClass' expected 0 arguments, got 2.`

I understand the error is because `MyClass` doesn't have `__init__` defined (if it's defined, there's no import error).

My question is: How can I import `MyClass.py`, which has `__new__` defined but not `__init__`?

(without going into the details of why I have `__new__` and not `__init__`)

Comment: MyClass is your own implemented class ?

Comment: @gachdavit Yes, which is then imported into Robot Framework.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you unwilling to create a `__init__` method that takes two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), `__new__` will pass the arguments it receives on to the `__init__`. Since you didn't create an `__init__` that accepts arguments, that's why you get the error.

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance *and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`*.

If you don't want the `__init__` to be called, you might get some help from  this question: [Possible to prevent init from being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187388/possible-to-prevent-init-from-being-called)

Comment: I see.  You and @gachdavit were both saying the same thing. I added `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass` and now it's working.  Tx!

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` is responsible on instance creation, and `__init__` is just initializer after instance is created. First always is called `__new__` and then `__init__`. `__new__` is always `@staticmethod` as a default, but you can use `@staticmethod` decorator also (same).

```
class Foo:

    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls):
        print('Foo.__new__ is called')
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        print(obj) # <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f82c1403588> This is "f" object.
        return obj

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Foo.__init__ is called !!!')

f = Foo()
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Tx, but this explains a property of `__new__` vs `__init__` but doesn't explain how I can import the class in Robot Framework.

Comment: You are welcome. `__new__` does not affect on import. I think you have problem, during instance creation process. Which class exactly import can not import from Robot framework ?